# "Content view not yet Created" on Android Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using Android Fragments with a `viewpager` setup.  Basically there are 5 tabs you can swipe through.

4 of the 5 contain `ListFragments` that are populated by MySQL tables; this is done inside of an `AsyncTask`.  When I swipe very fast I sometimes get this error:

```
09-01 07:54:01.243: E/AndroidRuntime(19706): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-01 07:54:01.243: E/AndroidRuntime(19706): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
09-01 07:54:01.243: E/AndroidRuntime(19706):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:328)
09-01 07:54:01.243: E/AndroidRuntime(19706):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.getListView(ListFragment.java:222)
09-01 07:54:01.243: E/AndroidRuntime(19706):    at com.---.---.MasterCat$TopFrag$TopTask.onPostExecute(MasterCat.java:570)
09-01 07:54:01.243: E/AndroidRuntime(19706):    at com.---.---.MasterCat$TopFrag$TopTask.onPostExecute(MasterCat.java:1)
09-01 07:54:01.243: E/AndroidRuntime(19706):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
09-01 07:54:01.243: E/AndroidRuntime(19706):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
09-01 07:54:01.243: E/AndroidRuntime(19706):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
09-01 07:54:01.243: E/AndroidRuntime(19706):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-01 07:54:01.243: E/AndroidRuntime(19706):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-01 07:54:01.243: E/AndroidRuntime(19706):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4928)
09-01 07:54:01.243: E/AndroidRuntime(19706):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-01 07:54:01.243: E/AndroidRuntime(19706):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-01 07:54:01.243: E/AndroidRuntime(19706):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
09-01 07:54:01.243: E/AndroidRuntime(19706):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
09-01 07:54:01.243: E/AndroidRuntime(19706):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have intentionly not used a `ProgressDialog` because it makes swiping stutter quite a bit.

So I have two options and I need help either way:

1. How to prevent this error and keep the list refreshing even while swiping.
2. OR once the 5 fragments are loaded, turn off 'refresh while swiping'.  In other words, the lists will stay the same unless you back out of the Activity and come back.

I'd prefer option #1.  Please let me know what code you need to see:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout);


        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        mViewPager
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

                    }
                });

        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }




    }

    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    }

    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment f = null;
            switch (position) {
            case 0: {
                f = new MasterFrag();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();

                f.setArguments(args);
                break;
            }
            case 1: {
                f = new FeaturedFrag();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();

                f.setArguments(args);
                break;
            }
            case 4: {
                f = new TopFrag();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();

                f.setArguments(args);
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                f = new NewFrag();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();

                f.setArguments(args);
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                f = new TrendFrag();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();

                f.setArguments(args);
                break;
            }
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("not this many fragments: "
                        + position);
            }

            return f;

        }
```

Also, line 570 referenced in the LogCat pertains to a getListView() inside of an AsyncTask which is inside of a ListFragment not shown above.

**EDIT**:

Adding one of the 5 Fragments - the one referenced in LogCat - "TopFrag"

```
class TopTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            String url_select = "http://www.---.com/---/---.php";

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Top", "Top"));

            try {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                // read content
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

            String item, cat;
            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject json_data = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    item = json_data.getString("item");
                    cat = json_data.getString("category");


                    items.add(item);
                    cats.add(cat);



                }
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Top Items Found",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            ListView listView;
            listView = getListView();
            listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long id) {
           // edit

                }
            });

            MasterCatObject[] mco = new MasterCatObject[items.size()];
            int index = 0;

            for (@SuppressWarnings("unused")
            String i : items) {
                mco[index] = new MasterCatObject(items.get(index),
                        cats.get(index));
                index++;
            }

            adapter = new AllTimeAdapter(getActivity(), mco);
            setListAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.getListView(ListFragment.java:222)
at com.---.---.MasterCat$TopFrag$TopTask.onPostExecute(MasterCat.java:570)
```

your `TopTask.onPostExecute()` must not touch the UI while the fragment is not yet (before `onCreateView`) / no longer (after `onDestroyView`) shown. There is simply no `ListView` you can get.

What you could do here is to update the datastructure that is used by the `ListView` so the next time the list is drawn the new data is included.

Comment: I am getting the `ListView` by the normal `getListView()` inside the PostExecute - would it be better to place it in the `OnActivityCreated`?

Comment: `OnActivityCreated` should work but I would put it in `onCreateView` after calling `super` since that is definately a place where you can be sure that it is called when the `ListView` is created.

Comment: Marking correct;  I can already see things are much more stable.

Comment: Also, the `for` loop you use to iterate over the items collection is a little counter intuitive.  You know that `items.get(index) == i`, assuming a `List`, because that's how Java's enhanced for loops work. I see you also need to get the same index from the `cats` collection. In this case, you might use a Map<String, String> from `item` to `category` or a collection of classes (say `MyPair`) that have two values: item and category -- in that case you could iterate over your collection of `MyPair`s and get all the data. I'd recommend a `Map` though since they are exactly for key-value pairs (=

Comment: In my `onPostExecute()` I only run my code for the listview if view is not null. Something like this: `if(getView() != null && getActivity() != null) { /*set listview's adapter or whatever*/}`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid crash can check if ListFragment isAdded())

in the moment of exception ListFragment is detached.